# Strip probuf structure names from binary

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I used protocol buffers to comunicate with my web server but i found that all fields name are hardcoded in binary, what could i do to strip them - protobuf doesnt need names - it's binary data format. Such things easly accessible can help with reverse engineering my app what i want to prevent. How to strip those values out from binary?

[image]

Comment: Try adding [`option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME;`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite) to your .proto files. This would cause `protoc` to generate classes derived from `MessageLite` rather than `Message`. The difference is, `MessageLite` doesn't support reflection and doesn't rely on `Descriptor` et al. I suspect that's where field names come from.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik but i'm using reflections in my code, so adding that option would cause that it will stop working?

Comment: Part of reflection is the ability to look up messages and fields by name; as well as to obtain names of messages and fields. Which of course requires that message and field names be present in the compiled binary. You can have reflection and names, or no reflection and no names; pick one.